# Allow and/or Deny of CIDR Value Woes

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm having some issues messing around with Allow/Deny, I've spent about 3 hours messing with it so far and have only frustration as a result.  I've read the Apache docs and several guides and I'm still stuck.

My issue is extremely simple or at least I feel that it should be... I want to block a CIDR range from hitting a particular area of my host.  In my testing server I've tried as far as I can tell every possibility of this..

```
<LocationMatch "/myjunk/.+">
    <IfModule mod_access.c>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from 10.1.1.100/32
        Allow from All
    </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

I've verified in my log file that I'm actually coming from 10.1.1.100, I've tried: switching to Order Allow,Deny; leaving off the /32; switching the Allow and Deny lines and switching the Order around.  If I remove the Allow from and set to Deny from All, I get the 403 which I want.

Snippet from log file:

```
15128 10.1.1.100 192.168.1.100 - - [01/Nov/2011:17:36:54 -0400] "GET /myjunk/abc/def/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 8000
```

I'm running Apache/2.0.58 on an old Solaris box, unfortunately there's nothing I can do to change that.  I have full access to the server, I can modify the httpd.conf file directly.

I have a feeling that I've overlooked something or just missing something small.

Comment: I love asking questions which no one seems to have an answer for!  It seems that I'm always either making a stupid mistake or found something really challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Order Deny,Allow` to `Order Allow,Deny` and try again.

Keep in mind that, with `deny,allow` order, `deny` directive is evaluated before the `allow` directive. If the client does not match `deny` rule or it does match `allow` rule, then it will be granted access.

In contrary with `allow,deny`: if the client does not match the `allow` rule or it does match `deny` rule, then it will be denied access.